# Spring Thymeleaf Whitelabel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I was trying to build a simple spring web app. The app works correctly but I am not being able to connect to the web server when using a Thymeleaf template.

The controller class is the following one:

```
@Controller() public class BookController { 
private final BookRepository bookRepository;
public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
}

@GetMapping("/books")
public String getBooks(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("bookList", bookRepository.findAll());
    return "books/list";
}
}
```

The HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Spring Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book List</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="book : ${bookList}">
        <td th:text="${book.id}">123</td>
        <td th:text="${book.title}"> Spring in Action</td>
        <td th:text="${book.isbn}">Wrox</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

My **directory tree** is the following one:

[image: Proyect´s Directory Tree]

I don´t get any error or exception, I just get the following blank page:

[image]

I´ve tried both '**@GetMapping**' and '**@RequestMapping**' and followed a few tutorials but i can´t figure out what is the issue.
I would be so thankful if someone could help me with this.

I managed to map the error and I only get the status code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGmSI.png

I have also tried to use the '**server.error.include-message=always**' property but i just get the following message: No message available

Comment: You have an error in the request, spring boot redirect to /error. You should provide error log.

Comment: You also want to rename the templates.books directory. The root should be templates and in templates you need the books directory that contains the list.html.

Comment: @LeeGreiner it´s just IntelliJ interpretating it that way. books is under templates when i see it from the Windows explorer.

Comment: @MetinBulak how could I redirect it to /error? I´ve tried creating a new class ErrorController but it doesn´t work either

Comment: Try adding `server.error.include-message=always` to your application.properties file to see a more detailed error message.

Comment: @larjae I just tried it and I only get the follwing message: No message available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]try your folder structure like this in the screen short

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the package controller was over the rest while the IDE interpretated like it was at the same level.

I just had to move the package to the same level and it works.